# What is a "byte", according to C11?

Tags: c, c11

[From the C11 draft standard, Section Chapter 1 Section 3:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

3.6
**byte**: addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character
set of the execution environment

NOTE 1 **It is possible to express the address of each individual byte of an object uniquely**.

So, do I interpret this correctly when I go to the conclusion that *only byte-addressable memory architectures are targeted by the standard?* Or is it that I am reading it in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you're right, this does say a conforming C implementation must have byte-addressable memory. But the C standard does not require that a byte have only eight bits. An implementation can define "byte" to have 64 bits, and that's just peachy as far as the standard is concerned. Nor does the standard require "byte-addressable" to be a single operation, so 8-bit bytes on a processor that only supports 64-bit reads can still be valid, so long as the compiler ensures that the required masking and shifting is performed to get the right result.

Comment: All three answers are good and clarifying. So I accept the highest voted. But what is a "basic character set"? It doesn't appear to be defined there?

Comment: @Vorac There's the basic source character set, and the basic execution character set. Basic execution character set is what's meant, it's defined in 5.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that you are reading the standard the wrong way.  I think that what it says is (paraphrasing):

> the smallest individually-addressable unit of memory which can contain
>   a member of the basic character set (...) is called a *byte*

that is, the standard defines what it means, within its scope, by the term *byte* and, thereby, rejects definitions of the same term from without the standard which do not conform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply put:
*As per the standard a byte is the smallest addressable memory location.*

Comment: No, I think the standard allows for bytes to be larger than the smallest addressable memory location.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: Why? And if not a byte, what do you think is the smallest adressable memory location?

Comment: The standard specifies two requirements for a byte: large enough for basic character set and memory addressable. On a system where the "basic character set" needs 16 bit, but units of 8 bit are addressable, a byte would need to be 16 bit IMO.

Comment: I agree with @PhilippWendler: the standard clearly states that a *byte* must be *large enough to hold any member of the basic character set*.  If that unit of memory is larger than the smallest unit of memory which is individually addressable then the standard says that a *byte* is larger than than that individually addressable unit of memory.  Imagine a basic character set requiring 12-bits to represent each character implemented on a machine with individually-addressable units of memory of 8-bits each.

Comment: It's the smallest unit of memory addressable *from C*. Any notion of addressability using another language (such as the instruction set of the CPU) is completely irrelevant to the definition in the C standard. Of course it's relevant to the person writing the compiler, since they have to emit some opcodes, so they might choose the size of the byte as is convenient for the CPU. The standard doesn't care whether it's convenient or not.

Comment: There exist processors (primarily intended for graphics) where all addresses are bit addresses.  If one were to use some non-standard means of creating a pointer `*p` to the third bit of a byte, then a write to `p` would modify five bits of one byte and three bits of another.  Even though the processor regards memory as bit-addressable, however, there is no means *defined within the C language specification* by which code could create a pointer which wasn't aligned to a byte boundary.